# Как узнать количество дней между датами исключив выходные?

Tags: запрос, sql

Здраствуйте! Есть таблица `IdStudenta/IdSpravki/Nachalo/Konec/Primechanie`.
Как мне просчитать количество дней со справками у студента, зная начало и конец справки, и при этом исключив выходные, а лучше еще, например создать таблицу "праздники" и вносить данные типа 8.03.2012= 8 марта и т.д. и что б эти даты исключались тоже.
В общем, хочу получить ответ вроде:

```
idstudent/idspravki/Count
1/1/ 20
```

(например, 1й студент по 1й справке 20 дней пропуска).

И вариант посложнее:
Если будет пересечение справок, например одна справка 1.1.2012-20.1.2012 -примечание-Бронхит, а другая 12.1.2012-28.1.2012 примечание -участие в конференции и надо отобразить в другом виде, например

```
idstudenta/idspravki/date/primechanie
1/ 1/ 1.1.2012/Бронхит
1/ 1/ 2.1.2012/Бронхит
.....
1/ 1/ 12.1.2012/Бронхит
1/ 2/ 12.1.2012/УЧАСТИЕ В КОНФЕРЕНЦИИ
...
```

Как сделать запрос, чтоб получить такой ответ?

Comment: @Роман Ракзин, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Answer (score 2):

1. Запрос простой см справку по datediff (какой sql вы не уточнили, ищите аналог, если это не mysql), количество праздников за период вычитайте из полученной разницы. [см пример SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9d62/2)
2. Здесь сложнее, точнее никак. Чтобы получить такой результат чисто запросом вам придется завести таблицу с днями, на каждый день по записи, это плохая идея. Лучше это делать в коде. циклом. Получаете за интервал все справки, бежите по датам и проверяете подходит или не подходит. ну там несложно, логика ваша, разберетесь.